# How can I capitalize the first letter in a string using mediawiki?

Tags: string, mediawiki, uppercase, wiktionary

How can I capitalize the first letter of a string (or of each word) in Mediawiki? In this case, the string is just a single word, so capitalizing every word's first letter is ok as well.

I want to do something like

```
{{#capitalize:string}}
```

and get output

```
String
```

I already tried with

```
{{#titleparts:mystring}}
```

but it doesn't alter my string at all (tried at http://sv.wiktionary.org)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `{{ucfirst:string}}`. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words for information on all built-in parser functions.